# how to get offset of inside element

Tags: reactjs, ref

if I want to receive a ref from this:

```
const ref1=useRef()
const ref2=useRef()

<div ref=ref1>

  <div ref=ref2>

  </div>

</div>
```

if I use `ref2.current.offsetTop` I get the offset of ref1, is there a way to get ref2 offset value?

Comment: Do you mean the space between ref2 and ref1 horizontally?

Comment: I need to scroll to ref2, with scroll to offset, so I need the exact offset of ref 2 @YTG

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to get information about the element position relative to the viewport:

```
const {x,y} = ref2.current.getBoundingClientRect();
window.scrollTo(x,y)
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but that doesn't work, if I am on the view itself it scrolls to a random place. I need the offset of the item on the window itself.